# How to set project-dir in dbt with environment variable?

Tags: python, ubuntu, environment-variables, dbt

I am trying to locate my dbt_project.yml file which is not in the root directory of my project. Previously, I was using an env var called DBT_PROJECT_DIR in order to define where dbt_project.yml file is located and it was working fine. In a similar way, I am using DBT_PROFILE_DIR and it still works correct. But I cannot make DBT_PROJECT_DIR work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is in development, see https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/6078

Comment: I'm guessing you may be aware of the `--project-dir`. This doesn't quite work for my use case though since I'm using an extension in the IDE that doesn't have the option to set that flag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain this is not supported. Are you not able to change the directory to the directory of the `dbt_project.yml` before running dbt commands?

As a workaround, could you just add `--project-dir $PROJECT_DIR` to every command you plan to run?

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed not supported, [this get_nearest_project_dir](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt/blob/159e79ee6ba86c852f4bf067dd0f1b6356135383/core/dbt/task/base.py#L114) function is used to find the project dir. That should be adjusted to allow for using a environment variable, similar to [profiles indeed](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt/blob/159e79ee6ba86c852f4bf067dd0f1b6356135383/core/dbt/config/profile.py#L24).

You could open an issue on Github, discuss adding this feature there.

Answer (score 0):

Both DBT_PROJECT_DIR and DBT_PROFILE_DIR work now.

documentation:

https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt_project.yml

https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/core/connect-data-platform/connection-profiles#advanced-customizing-a-profile-directory

Comment: The first line of my answer states that the 2 env variables `DBT_PROJECT_DIR` and `DBT_PROFILE_DIR` are supported. and the links are indeed used for reference.